# how to write directive 'ng-let' that binds an expression to a name

Tags: angularjs

I want to write a directive that mirrors ng-repeat but binds a name to a single variable:

so instead of writing something like this:

```
ng-repeat="summary in data.accounts.all.summaryAsArray()"
```

you can write something like this

```
ng-let="summary as data.accounts.all.summary();
        global.some.info as processSummary(summary);"
```

where:

```
data.accounts.all.summaryAsArray() returns [<obj>]

data.accounts.all.summary() returns <obj>
```

How would this be done?

---

An example of how this might be used is in a situation where you want to filter, sort and page the data, but you also want to reuse the steps of the bindings

```
ng-let="berts as data('users.list') | filterBy:select('name'):contains('Bert') | sort:by('date-joined');
        groups as berts | subArray:page.perpage:pagecurrent | groupBy:has('fish')
       "
```

Then you can use page accordingly in the child elements:

```
  ng-repeat="g in groups"

  or {{bert.length}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose here is to have a directive that adds a variable to the scope. Here's what the linking function could look like (I haven't tested it, but it shouldn't be too far off).

```
scope: false,
transclude: 'element',
link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
    // We want to evaluate "(variable) as (expression)"
    var regExp = /^\s*(.*)\s+as\s+(.*)\s*/,
        match = $attr.ngLet.match(regExp);

    if(!match) return; // Do nothing if the expression is not in a valid form

    var variableName = match[1],
        expression = match[2],
        assign = function(newValue) { $scope[variableName] = newValue; }

    // Initialize the variable in the scope based on the expression evaluation
    assign($scope.$eval(expression));

    // Update when it changes
    $scope.$watch(expression, assign);

}
```

**Edit:** Note that this will not deeply watch an array passed as an expression. Only if the reference changes.

**Edit 2:** To allow multiple definitions, small adjustments can be made:

```
scope: false,
transclude: 'element',
link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
    // We want to evaluate "(variable) as (expression)"
    var regExp = /^\s*(.*)\s+as\s+(.*)\s*/;

    angular.forEach($attr.ngLet.split(';'), function(value) {
        var match = value.match(regExp);

        if(!match) return;

        var variableName = match[1],
            expression = match[2],
            assign = function(newValue) { $scope[variableName] = newValue; };

        // Initialize the variable in the scope based on the expression evaluation
        assign($scope.$eval(expression));

        // Update when it changes
        $scope.$watch(expression, assign);
    });
}
```

Comment: If you do, changing the `$scope` passed in the linking function will not have any effect in subsequent element as they will be siblings and not parent-child. Also (and I will edit my answer) you will need to transclude to the element (`tranclude: 'element'`) for the directive to only affect binding within the element where it is applied. Otherwise, it will attach itself to the existing scope which will also affect other directives that are located before or after.

Comment: Thanks for your work. I haven't implemented your solution just yet... I've thought about it a bit more and it'll be nice to bind multiple params to the let, as well as to let it the ability to update existing vars. I've updated the question accordingly. Can you help with this? I'm sorry i haven't had time to properly explain the concept that I'm currently working on - which is minimising the use of controllers and laying out content purely based on filter transforms.

Comment: See my edit for the small changes needed. You just need a token to split the string expression with.

Comment: fantastic! I'll have a go at this with my project later today and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Its working really well. there was a small mistake which i've corrected and it does the job!

Comment: `scope: true` seems a more common use case to me, because it makes the new scope bindings local.