# How to avoid ng-init in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I want to show message when ng-repeat collection is empty i.e.:

```
<div ng-init="filteredArray=(array|filter:{...})">
    <h1 ng-if="!filteredArray.length">Empty array</h1>
    <table ng-if="filteredArray.length">
        <tr ng-repeat="element in filteredArray">
            <td>{{element}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that ng-init will not watch for modification of the source array. Any hint how to do it properly?

Comment: I don't find any error in your code if you are updating filteredArray from directive controller...ng-init won't watch after first initialization, that's a fact.

Comment: The problem is that the array is populated asynchronously (i.e. with REST HTTP request),  so when the user refresh the page it is empty when during the initial rendering and after a while the data will come but the ng-init-ed filteredArray will remain empty. I.e. something like ng-let from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355827/how-to-write-directive-ng-let-that-binds-an-expression-to-a-name can help but I'm looking for a standard way with build in directives.

Comment: Then why ng-if is not working? I think you should use $scope.$apply(); after HTTP request gets completed so that AngularJS digest cycle gets triggered and your DOM elements will get updated according to the filteredArray.

Comment: Do you think that $scope.$apply() will fool ng-init to reevaluate? I'm not so sure that it will.

Comment: It won't but it will update the DOM element and you might get your respective result...

Comment: IMHO the DOM will be updated only if the ng-repeat expression changes which is not the case here because ng-init doesn't watch for modification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116791/discussion-between-atanas-palavrov-and-ajay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create the filtered variable in the `ng-repeat`, and use that one:

```
<div>
    <h1 ng-if="!filteredArray.length">Empty array</h1>
    <table ng-if="filteredArray.length">
        <!-- here angular assigns the filtered array to the 'filteredArray' variable, 
        which then can be used -->
        <tr ng-repeat="element in filteredArray=(array|filter:{...})">
            <td>{{element}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

See also [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3sw0j2q/1/)

---

**EDIT**

If you don't like the ugly expression, you can also do something like this:

```
function myController ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.$watch("theFilter", function (val) {
        $scope.filteredArray = $filter("filter")($scope.array, val);
    });
}
```

And in your html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in filteredArray">
    ..
</tr>
```

Check in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3sw0j2q/3/)

Comment: Yep, I was looking for something like that. The logic is not obvious and the ng-repeat expression is more ugly and hard to read but it works as expected!

Comment: See extra answer ;)

Comment: Hmmm ... if I need to handle that in JS code then using custom ng-let will be more handy because I need that in lot of places. 

Also seems that that approach doesn't work in my real code which is more complex than the simple example here.

But the fact that variables can be assigned in the ng-repeat is a nice feature that I didn't know. Appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check ng-repeats $last to show your message like below

```
<div ng-repeat="n in data track by $index">
   <h1 ng-if="$last">Empty array</h1>

</div>
```

In your case you can have a variable at the table level and then set it to $last,when it'll be true your message will show like below

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-init='counter=false'>
         <h1 ng-if='counter'>Empty array</h1>
      <table ng-if="myData.length">
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="element in myData track by $index" ng-init="counter=$last">
            <td>{{element}}
            <ng-if ng-init='sync($last)'/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Your controller should look like below

```
var app=angular.module('app',[])

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

  $scope.myData=['a','b','c']
  $scope.sync=function(val)
  {
    alert(val)
    $scope.counter=val
  }
})
```

Comment: This is clever but will not work in my case because I want to replace the table with something but the ng-repeat will be in the nested tr tag i.e. the structure is not the same.

Comment: This probably will solve it. But it is too complex for such a trivial problem. IMHO the best way is to use ng-let which watches the expression. I was trying to avoid adding dependency to 3th party directive and curious if there is another way. The usage of $last variable can be really helpful in some other cases, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stored `(array|filter:{...})` value into `filteredArray`, you cannot modify it in the template.

You should repeat `(array|filter:{...})` code in the template.

```
<h1 ng-if="!(array|filter:{...}).length">Empty array</h1>
<table ng-if="(array|filter:{...}).length">
    <tr ng-repeat="element in (array|filter:{...})">
        <td>{{element}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that repetition of the same sub-expression. Code repetition is a good hint that there is something wrong in the design. Otherwise this is technically correct solution.